# Execute a single query using a different database. Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Ruby on Rails project where I want to let the user execute SQL SELECT queries.

For safety purposes, I have two mysql databases. One of them is my main database, with user information and so on.
The second database is intended to hold the "test" tables where the users are supposed to be able to SELECT stuff from using a specific database user that I granted "select" permission.

Basically, I want my user to submit a query, then I want to change to my test database, run that query, return a result, and then go back to my old database.

**Database.yml**

```
mysql: &mysql
  adapter: mysql
  database: sql_detective
  user: root
  password: root
  timeout: 5000

mysql_tests: &mysql_tests
  adapter: mysql
  database: sql_detective_tests
  user: user
  password: user
  timeout: 5000

test:
  <<: *mysql_tests
development:
  <<: *mysql
```

**Funcionario.rb**

```
class Funcionario < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :test
end
```

**stages_controller.rb**

```
@query = Funcionario.find_by_sql(params[:query])
```

**When I try to execute the query, I get this error:**

```
Mysql::Error in StagesController#sql_query

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

**Fix**

*database.yml*

Changing user to username fixed it all.

Like so...

**before**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: sql_detective
  user: root
  password: root
  timeout: 5000
```

**after**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: sql_detective
  username: root
  password: root
  timeout: 5000
```